# Perl regex to subsitute a pattern excluding another pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string as below.

```
$line = 'this is my string "hello world"';
```

I want to have a regex to delete all space characters inside the string except the region "Hello world".

I use below to delete space chars but it deletes all of them.

```
$line=~s/ +//g;
```

How can I exclude the region between "Hello world" and i get the string as below?

```
thisismystring"hello world"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you probably want to handle quoted strings properly, you should have a look at the [Text::Balanced](http://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aBalanced) module.

Use that to split your text into quoted parts and non-quoted parts, then do the replacement on the non-quoted parts only, and finally join the string together again.

Comment: +1, as it's definitely more bulletproof solution than mine. )

Comment: Can you please add some example code for this question's problem?

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's one way to do it:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $l = 'this is my string "hello world some" one two three "some hello word"';
$l =~ s/ +(?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)+$)//g;

print $l;
# thisismystring"hello world some"onetwothree"some hello word"
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/g1jwi5fk).

But I really wonder shouldn't it be done the other way (by tokenizing the string, for example), especially if the quotes may be unbalanced.

Answer (score 0):

```
s/\s+(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)//g
```

Test the code [here](http://ideone.com/gqaHv).

Answer (score 0):

[Another regex to do it](http://regexr.com?31rdq):

```
s/(\s+(".*?")?)/$2/g
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub main {
  my $line = 'this is my string "hello world"';
  while ($line =~ /(\w*|(?:"[^"]*"))\s*/g) { print $1;}
  print "\n";
}

main;
```